# Finding the length of a string in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hello World"

.text
    main:
        li $t0, 0 # initialize loop-counter
        la $a0, message #load the address of the 1st byte

    loop:
        lb $t1, ($a0) # load the content of the address stored in $a0
        beq $t1, $zero, exit    # branch if equal
                    # exit the program if $t0 == null 

        addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the loop counter
        addi $a0, $a0, 1 # go to next byte      

        j loop 

    exit:
        move $a0, $t0 # prepare to print the integer
        li $v0, 1 # integer syscall
        syscall

        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Apparently, this program is working well.

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Is there anything with this program which I am overlooking or which I should pay special attention to?
2. What if I use `$v0`, in place of `$t1`? What difference does it make?

Comment: _"What if I use $v0, in place of $t1? What difference does it make?"_ None.